# Validar Formulários no Materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Como posso fazer a validação de formulários pelo Materialize?

Estou tentando utilizar o `jquery-validate` para isso mas não funciona, coloco as regras e mesmo quando uma regra é invalida o campo ainda fica verde.

Como posso fazer para que o campo só fique verde quando ele está valido?

**Meu código Formulário:**

```
<form id="testeMaterialize">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="number" id="nome" name="nome" class="validate" minlength="5" required>
            <label for="nome" data-error="Preencha o campo Nome" class="active">Nome</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" class="validate" required >
                <label for="numero" data-error="Preencha o campo Numero corretamente" class="active">Numero</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Meu Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    validator = $("#testeMaterialize").validate({
        rules: {
            nome: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            numero: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 11,
                maxlength: 14
            }
        },

        messages: {
            nome: {
                required: "Por favor preencha o campo Nome",
                minlength: "O Campo nome deve ter no minimo 5 caracteres"
            },
            numero: {
                required: "Por favor preencha o campo Numero",
                minlength: "O Campo número deve ter no mínimo 11 caracteres",
                maxlength: "O Campo número deve ter no máximo 14 caracteres"
            }
        },
        errorElement : 'div',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var placement = $(element).data('error');
        if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error)
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Vc quer validar no Banco ou apenas que mostrar do lado do usuário que o campo está invalido? Se for apenas por uma questão de UX e trocar a cor pro invalido vc resolve isso com CSS não precisa de JS

Comment: Seria para o cliente. Pensei que conseguiria fazer isso com o Materialize e o Jquery-Validator.

Comment: Gladson se quiser eu faço um exemplo simples de como vc valida só com CSS pelo lado do cliente mesmo. Mas para validar no Banco não é seguro. O CSS e o HTML são apenas criar algumas regras para o Input e estilizar vermelho ou verde por exemplo. Se quiser um exemplo me fala.

Comment: Eu quero Cara. Vai me ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se pode te interessar, mas vou te dar uma resposta utilizando apenas a validação pelo lado do Cliente.

O Materialize já tem alguns estilos próprias para mostrar a validação do input. No caso ele troca a cor da linha onde está escrito o valor do input, então não vou mexer nisso...

Fiz apenas algumas regras para validar o `<input>` pelo lado do cliente no próprio Browser

```
pattern="[A-Za-zÀ-ú\s]+$"  //O pattern do campo só aceita letras, acentos etc
pattern="[0-9]+$"          //O pattern do campo só aceita números
required                   //o campo é de preenchimento obrigatório
minlength="2"              //tem que ter no mínimo 2 caracteres 
maxlength="20"             //e no máximo 20 caracteres
```

**Segue o exemplo:**

- No campo Nome só aceita texto, ***não aceita números***, e tem que ter no mínimo 2 caracteres e no máximo 20 caracteres.
- No campo número ele só aceita valores entre 1 e 20, não aceita 0 e nem 21 por exemplo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<form id="testeMaterialize">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="validate" required pattern="[A-Za-zÀ-ú\s]+$" required minlength="2" maxlength="20">
            <label for="nome" data-error="Preencha o campo Nome" class="active">Nome</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="number" id="numero" name="numero" class="validate" required pattern="[0-9]+$" required min="1" max="20">
            <label for="numero" data-error="Preencha o campo Numero corretamente" class="active">Numero</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**OBS:** Sempre use o `<input type="">` correto para o tipo de informação que vc quer tipo, e-mail, telefone, etc... pois todos eles já têm uma "validação intrínseco" feita pelo HTML5, por exemplo o `<input type="email">` tem que ter um **@**, vc não precisa definir isso, essa já é uma regra *default* do *tipo:email*.

Link com documentação do Inpute Tipes:https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.